# give some screenshots to create UIBackgroundModes key in Info.plist for iOS4

Tags: ios, uibackgroundmode

I'm new to iPhone development.I have already gone through some of the exploring pages to create UIBackgroundModes key in Info.plist for iOS4 .But it is little bit difficult to understand . Kindly provide some step by step procedure with screenshot example for easy understanding...also specify what the requirements which are needed ie iPhone, OS version 4.0...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42302369/5175709) for more clarification on how to use Xcode capabilities or plist

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The UIBackgroundModes key identifies which background tasks your application supports. Its value is an array that contains one or more strings with the following values:

- audio – The application plays audible content to the user while in the background.
- location – The application keeps users informed of their location, even while running in the background.
- voip – The application provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.

You can edit the Info.plist file on Xcode. To add a new key, click on the *+* sign and write:

**iOS 4**

"*UIBackgroundModes*" as the key, make sure the type is set to string and then in value write *audio*, *location* or *voip* depending on your needs:
[image: Info.plist]

**iOS 6**

"*Required background modes*" as the key and then set the type in drop down menu.

[image]

Comment: thank you; I was banging my head looking for a specific "UIBackgroundModes" key in my plist

Answer (score 4):

In IOS 13. It would be like the list given below.

[image]

Comment: Can you give any official documentation link to this?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the link to the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uibackgroundmodes

Name: "`Required background modes`"
Type: Array of strings

Valid values:

- audio
- location
- voip
- external-accessory
- bluetooth-central
- bluetooth-peripheral
- fetch
- remote-notification
- processing