# How to run socket.io in the background on iOS in a React Native app?

Tags: ios, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, react-native

I am using `socket.io` in an `iOS React Native(v0.20) app`. The app tracks my location, and when my position changes it emits a message to a server. If the socket connection is lost the server sends an email to notify me.

I have the location tracking working in the background with [react-native-location](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location), but I can't get `socket.io` to work. When ever I change apps or turn off the screen, the app keeps tracking my location but I lose the socket connection.

Is there a way to run `socket.io` in the background like location tracking ? Short of that is there some native code that will allow me to maintain a `client/server connection` while in the background?

I know there is a [WebSocket alternative](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/WebSocket) but I can't see a way to get it to run in the background.

**UPDATE:**
I doubled checked my `Info.plist`, it has the necessary background values set already for [react-native-location](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location). I don't know if it matters but the socket work and location tracking are done in the same component.

[image]

**LocationComponent.js**

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
const io = require('socket.io-client/socket.io');
const socket = io(url, {jsonp: false});

import React, { Text, View, DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
import { RNLocation } from 'NativeModules';

export default GeolocationExample = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function() {
    RNLocation.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
    RNLocation.startUpdatingLocation();
    RNLocation.setDistanceFilter(3.0);
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('locationUpdated', locationObject => {
      this.props.newPosition({ longitude: locationObject.coords.longitude, latitude: locationObject.coords.latitude });
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    const { lastPosition, distance } = this.props;
    socket.emit('newPos', { longitude: lastPosition.longitude, latitude: lastPosition.latitude, distance, time: Date() });
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> {distance} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the behavior similar on iOS and Android or is this an iOS-only issue?

Comment: I haven't tried Android. This is my first React Native app and I wanted to focus on building for iOS so I could use it on my phone.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @ChrisAndersson no I have not. The best advice I can find is to build a package that will bridge the javascript I need to run with the native code that can run it. I don't actually know how to do that yet.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled I found this, but haven't got it to work. https://gist.github.com/liamzebedee/67e1b2c53c6c5edcf8ec

Comment: Any update on this ?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way you can do this "the right way".

**Edit**

From Apple's [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW6) :

> Implementing Long-Running Tasks
>
> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must
>   request specific permissions to run them in the background without
>   their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to
>   run in the background:
>
> Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
>   such as a music player app
>
> Apps that record audio content while in the
>   background
>
> Apps that keep users informed of their location at all
>   times, such as a navigation app
>
> Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
>
> Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
>
> Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
>
> Apps that implement these services must declare the services they
>   support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of
>   those services. Declaring the services lets the system know which
>   services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that
>   actually prevent your application from being suspended.

This being said, there is a working technique exist to keep your socket open :

Play a silent sound and set the background mode to audio. Check [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140806111426/http://tapbots.com/blog/pastebot/pastebot-music-in-background) for more information on the matter (it's a bit old but still valid). This will allow you to keep your socket open faking an audio app. Your info.plist should be updated to allow audio to run in the background.
`UIBackgroundModes`should be set to `audio` (check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW6) for more information)

Comment: I'm already running location checks in the background. As I've shown, I have it set in the info.plist. Shouldn't that already take care of it?

Answer (score 3):

I know there are hacks to get this done (i.e. the `audio` hack), but there's a reason iOS doesn't allow long running tasks in the background - please rethink your design to allow a better product.

Using log running tasks will deplete the battery. If you need data updates, register to get push notifications using the Apple push service (it's free, if your doing it directly, or it was last time I dealt with a similar issue).

Location tracking, specifically, is an allowed background system service, consider using the native API for this.

As to pushing the data to the server, you won't be able to (and probably shouldn't) maintain a long lasting connection with the server.

Consider collecting data and uploading to the server the collected batch every once in a while - preferably when the app is reopened, so you don't waste resources in the background and get people upset about their battery life and their data consumption.

Comment: I'm not concerned about battery life at the moment. I'd rather fix that issue after I have a working example of the app first. The point of the app is to share live updates racers, everyone needs to be in constant communication. If I wait too long to report a runners position then everyone loses out.

Comment: You're not concerned, but Apple was when it designed the API, hence the limits.... Maybe the racers can keep the app in the foreground.

Comment: While that works on a base level, it is far from ideal. When I run I turn on my music and turn off the phone screen so leaving the app in the foreground isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

iOS is fairly restrictive on the kind of processes it allows [when an app is backgrounded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

There seems to be some discussion around this on the socket.io client [issue tracker](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/146).

It seems someone got the socket connection to remain active if they set the background mode to `audio`. YMMV

Make sure you're setting the correct values in the UIBackgroundModes section of the Info.plist file. [How to do this in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413828/252431)

Comment: I had already set the values in Info.plist for `react-native-location`, and as I mentioned in the question, the location tracking works.  I've added a picture of the Info.plist values to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your picture of the Info.plist, it only allows the following three [background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

1. Background fetch
2. Location updates
3. Remote notifications

   You should allow "Audio and AirPlay" mode and it seems like "App plays audio or streams audio/video using Airplay".