# UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key issue. How do I fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I archive and publish my app to the App Store, I have the following error:

> WARNING ITMS-90339: "Deprecated Info.plist Key. The Info.plist contains a key 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' in bundle ar [ar.app] that will soon be unsupported. Remove the key, rebuild your app and resubmit."

But I don't have that key.

[image: My information file]

Answer (score 25):

You do have that key. It's labeled as "Application does not run in background". Remove that key from Info.plist.

Here's a little trick. Select the Info.plist. Then right-click on any key or value and select "Show Raw Keys/Values". Now you will see `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`.

Comment: Deprecated - The system now automatically suspends apps leaving the foreground when they don’t require background execution. For more information, see About the Background Execution Sequence.

Answer (score 4):

As @maddy suggested You need to remove "Application does not run in background" key in info.plist.

If you want to make sure that your app runs in background, you can use UIBackgroundModes key in Info.plist, you can refer to below link for examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413828/4525717, if this key is included, Apple would need valid justification for App store Approval process.